# MDX run slower in SSRS than in Management Studio

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

This is my issue:

I have an mdx dataset for a SSRS report. Running MDX in Management Studio takes 1 sec, but in report it takes 1 minute. This is a critical report and the user want it as fast as possible. I have noticed that in the view ExecutionLog3 of the ReportingServices database, the dataretrieval causes takes the most opf the time.

The MDX uses calculated members which use DESCENDANTS function which I putted in a declared set because of performance.

Maybe this is an administration or a networking issue?

Could someone advise what to do to lower the report execution time?

```
with

member [Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].[Other Branded] AS NULL
member [Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].[Total Branded] AS NULL
member [Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].[Total Own Branded] AS NULL
member [Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].[Total] AS NULL
set DescUmbArtCat as
DESCENDANTS(StrToset("{[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].&[118],[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].&[602]}"), 2)
Set DescUmbArt as
DESCENDANTS(Strtoset("{[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].&[118]}"), 2)
member SalesCY as 
[Measures].[Sales]

member TotalMktGrossSalesCY  AS 
       SUM(DESCENDANTS({[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].CURRENTMEMBER}, 2)
              , [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales])
member TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat)
              , [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales])
member TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales])
member TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[1], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales])
member TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalCategory as 
       SUM(DescUmbArtCat
              , [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales])
member TotalMktGrossSalesCYOtherBranded as 
       iif(TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected=0, null,TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected)

member SmallFormatGrossSalesCY AS 
       SUM(DESCENDANTS({[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].CURRENTMEMBER}, 2)
              , [Measures].[Small Format Market Gross Sales])
member SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat)
              , [Measures].[Small Format Market Gross Sales])
member SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Small Format Market Gross Sales])
member SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[1], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Small Format Market Gross Sales])
member SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalCategory as 
       SUM(DescUmbArtCat
              , [Measures].[Small Format Market Gross Sales])
member SmallFormatGrossSalesCYOtherBranded as 
       iif(SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected=0, null,SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected)


member LargeFormatGrossSalesCY AS 
       SUM(DESCENDANTS({[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].CURRENTMEMBER}, 2)
              ,[Measures].[Large Format Market Gross Sales])
member LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat)
              ,[Measures].[Large Format Market Gross Sales])
member LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Large Format Market Gross Sales])
member LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[1], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Large Format Market Gross Sales])
member LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalCategory as 
       SUM(DescUmbArtCat
              ,[Measures].[Large Format Market Gross Sales])
member LargeFormatGrossSalesCYOtherBranded as 
       iif(LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected=0, null,LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected)

member TotalMCCGrossSalesCY AS 
       SUM(DESCENDANTS({[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].CURRENTMEMBER}, 2)
              ,[Measures].[Total MCC Gross Sales])
member TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat)
              ,[Measures].[Total MCC Gross Sales])
member TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Total MCC Gross Sales])
member TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[1], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Total MCC Gross Sales])
member TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalCategory as 
       SUM(DescUmbArtCat
              ,[Measures].[Total MCC Gross Sales])
member TotalMCCGrossSalesCYOtherBranded as 
       iif(TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected=0, null,TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected)


member TraderMCCGrossSalesCY AS 
       SUM(DESCENDANTS({[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].CURRENTMEMBER}, 2)
              ,[Measures].[Trader MCC Gross Sales])
member TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat)
              ,[Measures].[Trader MCC Gross Sales])
member TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Trader MCC Gross Sales])
member TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[1], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Trader MCC Gross Sales])
member TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalCategory as 
       SUM(DescUmbArtCat
              ,[Measures].[Trader MCC Gross Sales])
member TraderMCCGrossSalesCYOtherBranded as 
       iif(TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected=0, null,TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected)

member SCOMCCGrossSalesCY AS 
       SUM(DESCENDANTS({[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].CURRENTMEMBER}, 2)
              ,[Measures].[SCO MCC Gross Sales])
member SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat)
              ,[Measures].[SCO MCC Gross Sales])
member SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt)
              ,[Measures].[SCO MCC Gross Sales])
member SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[1], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[SCO MCC Gross Sales])
member SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalCategory as 
       SUM(DescUmbArtCat
              ,[Measures].[SCO MCC Gross Sales])
member SCOMCCGrossSalesCYOtherBranded as 
       iif(SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected=0, null,SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded -SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected)

member MaxDate as
max(filter(StrToMember("([Time].[YM].[Month Name].&[201501])"):StrToMember("([Time].[YM].[Month Name].&[201505])"),TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalBrandedSelected <> NULL),[Time].[YM].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)

member MarketPriceCY  AS 
       SUM(DESCENDANTS({[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].CURRENTMEMBER}, 2)
              , [Measures].[Market Price])
member MarketPriceCYTotalBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat)
              ,[Measures].[Market Price])
member MarketPriceCYTotalBrandedSelected as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt)
              ,[Measures].[Market Price])
member MarketPriceCYTotalOwnBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[1], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Market Price])
member MarketPriceCYTotalCategory as 
       SUM(DescUmbArtCat
              , [Measures].[Market Price])
member MarketPriceCYOtherBranded as 
       iif(MarketPriceCYTotalBranded -MarketPriceCYTotalBrandedSelected=0, null,MarketPriceCYTotalBranded -MarketPriceCYTotalBrandedSelected)

member MCCPriceCY  AS 
       SUM(DESCENDANTS({[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].CURRENTMEMBER}, 2)
              , [Measures].[MCC Price])
member MCCPriceCYTotalBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat)
              ,[Measures].[MCC Price])
member MCCPriceCYTotalBrandedSelected as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt)
              ,[Measures].[MCC Price])
member MCCPriceCYTotalOwnBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[1], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[MCC Price])
member MCCPriceCYTotalCategory as 
       SUM(DescUmbArtCat
              , [Measures].[MCC Price])
member MCCPriceCYOtherBranded as 
       iif(MCCPriceCYTotalBranded -MCCPriceCYTotalBrandedSelected=0, null,MCCPriceCYTotalBranded -MCCPriceCYTotalBrandedSelected)

MEMBER SalesCov AS 
sum((FILTER( DESCENDANTS([Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].CURRENTMEMBER, 2), [Measures].[Market Price] <> NULL)), [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales])
                           / TotalMktGrossSalesCY

MEMBER SalesCovTotalBranded AS 
SUM((FILTER( ([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat), [Measures].[Market Price] <> NULL)), [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales])
                           / TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalBranded

MEMBER SalesCovTotalOwnBranded AS 
SUM((FILTER( ([Article].[Branded Label].&[1], DescUmbArtCat), [Measures].[Market Price] <> NULL)), [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales])
                           /  TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded


MEMBER SalesCovTotalCategory AS 
SUM((FILTER(DescUmbArtCat, [Measures].[Market Price] <> NULL)), [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales])
                           / TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalCategory

MEMBER SalesCovOtherBranded AS 
   iif( SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat), [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales]) -SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt), [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales])=0, null,
(SUM((FILTER( ([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat), [Measures].[Market Price] <> NULL)), [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales]) -SUM((FILTER( ([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt), [Measures].[Market Price] <> NULL)), [Measures].[Total Market Gross Sales]))
                           / TotalMktGrossSalesCYOtherBranded
)

member MaxDatePrice as
max(filter(StrToMember("([Time].[YM].[Month Name].&[201501])"):StrToMember("([Time].[YM].[Month Name].&[201505])"),MarketPriceCYTotalBrandedSelected<> NULL),[Time].[YM].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)

member LinearMetersCY  AS 
       SUM(DESCENDANTS({[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].CURRENTMEMBER}, 2)
              , [Measures].[Linear Meters])
member LinearMetersCYTotalBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArtCat)
              , [Measures].[Linear Meters])
member LinearMetersCYTotalBrandedSelected as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Linear Meters])
member LinearMetersCYTotalOwnBranded as 
       SUM(([Article].[Branded Label].&[1], DescUmbArt)
              , [Measures].[Linear Meters])
member LinearMetersCYTotalCategory as 
       SUM(DescUmbArtCat
              , [Measures].[Linear Meters])
member LinearMetersCYOtherBranded as 
       iif(LinearMetersCYTotalBranded -LinearMetersCYTotalBrandedSelected=0, null,LinearMetersCYTotalBranded -LinearMetersCYTotalBrandedSelected)

member MaxDateSpace as
max(filter(StrToMember("([Time].[YM].[Month Name].&[201501])"):StrToMember("([Time].[YM].[Month Name].&[201505])"),LinearMetersCYTotalBrandedSelected<> NULL),[Time].[YM].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)

member [Article].[Branded Label].[1] as 
       [Article].[Branded Label].&[1]

SELECT {TotalMktGrossSalesCY , TotalMktGrossSalesCYOtherBranded, TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalBranded, TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded, TotalMktGrossSalesCYTotalCategory,
SmallFormatGrossSalesCY , SmallFormatGrossSalesCYOtherBranded, SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBranded, SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded, SmallFormatGrossSalesCYTotalCategory,
LargeFormatGrossSalesCY , LargeFormatGrossSalesCYOtherBranded, LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalBranded, LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded, LargeFormatGrossSalesCYTotalCategory,
TotalMCCGrossSalesCY , TotalMCCGrossSalesCYOtherBranded, TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded, TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded, TotalMCCGrossSalesCYTotalCategory,
TraderMCCGrossSalesCY , TraderMCCGrossSalesCYOtherBranded, TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded, TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded, TraderMCCGrossSalesCYTotalCategory,
SCOMCCGrossSalesCY , SCOMCCGrossSalesCYOtherBranded, SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalBranded, SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalOwnBranded, SCOMCCGrossSalesCYTotalCategory,
MarketPriceCY , MarketPriceCYOtherBranded, MarketPriceCYTotalBranded, MarketPriceCYTotalOwnBranded, MarketPriceCYTotalCategory,
MCCPriceCY , MCCPriceCYOtherBranded, MCCPriceCYTotalBranded, MCCPriceCYTotalOwnBranded, MCCPriceCYTotalCategory,
SalesCov, SalesCovOtherBranded, SalesCovTotalBranded, SalesCovTotalOwnBranded, SalesCovTotalCategory, 
LinearMetersCY , LinearMetersCYOtherBranded, LinearMetersCYTotalBranded, LinearMetersCYTotalOwnBranded, LinearMetersCYTotalCategory,
MaxDate, MaxDatePrice, MaxDateSpace
} on columns

,{
iif(strtoset("{[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].&[118]}").count>16 or strtoset("{[Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Main Cat].&[412],
                                                        [Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Main Cat].&[853],
                                                        [Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Main Cat].&[856],
                                                       [Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Main Cat].&[858],
                                                                                            [Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Main Cat].&[877]}")

.count>20,null,
{(order(([Article].[Branded Label].&[0], topcount(Strtoset
              ("{[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].&[118]}")
                     , 16, (SalesCY ))), SalesCY  , desc))
,([Article].[Branded Label].&[0],[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].[Other Branded])
,([Article].[Branded Label].&[0],[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].[Total Branded])
,([Article].[Branded Label].[1],[Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].[Total Own Branded])
,([Article].[Branded Label], [Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].[Total])})
}

on rows
FROM TPT0300
where 
(StrToMember("([Time].[YM].[Month Name].&[201501])"):StrToMember("([Time].[YM].[Month Name].&[201505])") ,
Strtoset("{[Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Sub Cat].&[824]&[2],
[Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Sub Cat].&[1720]&[4],
[Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Sub Cat].&[863]&[2],
[Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Sub Cat].&[2400]&[6],
[Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Sub Cat].&[866]&[2],
[Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Sub Cat].&[273]&[1],
[Article].[Buying Domain].[PCG Sub Cat].&[247]&[1]}
")
)
```

Comment: How many rows are returned for that dataset?

Comment: The script have a parameter which are used as rows + 4 dynamic rows. Also, MDX creates 54 columns (measures). For this particular example, the parameter has 1 component, meaning 5 rows and 54 measures

Comment: Check for any hidden datasets in the report. Sometimes they are created without your knowledge by the engine while declaring parameter.

Comment: There are no hidden datasets.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the MDX code?

Comment: Now you can find the code I use in the question.

Comment: What is the value of `TimeDataRetrieval` for the report when you query the `ExecutionLog3`? Also from where are you running the report? Visual Studio? Report Server?

Comment: TimeDataRetrieval = 55266
    TimeProcessing = 543
    TimeRendering = 410
    Source = Live
    ByteCount = 384369
    RowCount = 198

Comment: and how do u access the report? Have you tried using the profiler? Use the Query begin and Query end events on it.

Comment: I run the report from Data Tools and from our application interface and it behaves the same. I've already used the profiler on it. Query Subcubes take 7% from the Query End. 50% takes Calculate Non Empty Ends.

Comment: You have a `Calculate Non Empty Ends` event in the profiler trace but dont have a `NON EMPTY` clause in the query you pasted!! Are you positive your code doesn't have a `NON EMPTY`  clause anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, the code doesn't have any NON EMPTY. 
In the profiler trace, the Query Non Empty Ends have 2 on the Integer column, meaning it performs a fast calculation. Or it should do this!

Comment: In SSMS if you change the where clause from 201501 to 201502 is it still 1 second? I'm wondering if you are seeing cold or warm cache performance in SSMS. Also what user does this query run under in SSRS vs. SSMS? What version and service pack of SSAS?

Comment: Changing 201501 to 201502 has the same result. The user is the same. the version of SSAS is Enterprise64 11.0.3000.0 with Service Pack 1

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The source of the issue was the set DescUmbArtCat which come from a parameter. 
There was another selection with [Articlegroup].[Umbrella Art].&[-1]. That's why the DESCENDATS takes so long. 
Filtering the parameter solved the problem.

Thank you all for your support!